C++/CLI Winforms. E2244 "a member of the managed class cannot belong to the unmanaged class type"
Im learning c++ for now and trying to create a vector of custom data type Employee.
Employee.h code:
public ref class Employee {
public:
    System::String^ name;
    int age;
    Employee() {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
    }
    Employee(System::String^ n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
};

Employee.cpp code:
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<Employee^> employees;

    employees.push_back(gcnew Employee("Alice", 20));
    employees.push_back(gcnew Employee("Bob", 22));

    return 0;
}

When i was tried to initialize vector<Employee> in MyForm.h, like this:
private: std::vector<Employee^> Employees;

There is happening error on " ^ " : E2244 a member of the managed class cannot belong to the unmanaged class type.
I tried using different pointers, as well as creating a copy constructor for the Employee class (I tried to find similar situations with other people), but this caused even more errors. Perhaps the mistake is trivial and simple, but unfortunately I don't have much time to dive into the theory. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I will be very glad if you can explain in detail.

C++ and C++/CLI are not the same thing. Errors starting with E are intellisense. Compile the program and get the error starting with C.

Use a C++/CLI (i.e. .NET) List<Employee^>  (System::Collections::Generic::List<Employee^>). std::vector is for non-managed classes.

@wohlstad I decided to try to do this using a vector, because of its more convenient way to access the elements. Of course, I'll try using the list, but I don't think this will be the best solution.
I think, that "set" has the same situation as vector in the cli?

Alternatively to @wohlstad's good suggestion, one can use STL/CLR's cliext::vector<> to fully maintain value-semantics

@ildjarn It's funny, but I tried to use cliext::vector, but I got a similar error...

You must be mistaken – there are no unmanaged types involved in cliext::vector<Employee>, so the error couldn't be that similar...

C++ and C++/CLI are different languages:
C++/CLI is the .NET version of native C++.
You cannot use a native C++ container like std::vector to hold .NET objects like your Employee.
Instead you should use a C++/CLI (i.e. .NET) container.
One such cadidate is System::Collections::Generic::List, as it it somewhat similar to std::vector, with a continous memory layout for the elemenets, and random access to them.
In your case it will be:
System::Collections::Generic::List<Employee^> ^ employees = 
                      gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<Employee^>();
employees->Add(gcnew Employee("Alice", 20));
employees->Add(gcnew Employee("Bob", 22));


The latter example is highly non-idiomatic – cliext::vector<Employee^>^ is akin to std::vector<Employee*>* and bluntly, nobody would ever do that. The point of STL/CLR is to use value-semantics, like C++, so one wouldn't put a handle-to-ref-type in any of its containers (and likewise one probably wouldn't gcnew the container itself, unless it saved a slew of %s later in the function). See C++ Stack Semantics for Reference Types

@ildjarn point taken - thanks. As I am not really familiar with STL/CLR I'll remove the latter example and keep the one I am familiar with for now. I'll read more about it later on.
